# installation problem for Ubuntu 22.04 on new machine

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 using a installation usb stick on an Acer Aspire 7:

- AMD Ryzen 5 5500U 2.10 GHz - 4 GHz, 6-Core 8 MB
- Intel SoC
- DDR4-RAM SO-DIMM
- nVidia GeForce GTX 1650 4 GB GDDR6

I do not want a dual boot. Ubuntu 22.04 cannot be installed properly. I tried also other distros like Debian or Mint without success. The only way to start the USB installer is the safe graphics (or compatibility mode). It seems to indicate a problem with nouveau. Through the safe graphics mode it is possible to install Ubuntu 22.04, but still it cannot be booted, afterwards. I was able to restart the system once, after installing only the minimal version without the proprietary software and drivers options. But after the first updating of the system the booting was not working any more.

I am getting the following error messages during the boot:

```
 [....] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
 [....] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
 /dev/nvme01np2: recovering journal
 /dev/nvme01np2: clean, 213468/31227904 files, 6120608/124895488 blocks
 [....] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
 [....] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
```

And afterwards,

```
 [....] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: PDMAO: 01000000 [] ch 0 [00ff8ff000 DRM] subc 0 mthd 0008 data 00000000
```

which is repeated hundreds of times with a slightly increasing time stamp.

I wonder whether the error might be connected to the GTX 1650 GPU, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

1. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 through the safe graphics mode, minimal version, no proprietary software or drivers and no downloads during installations.
2. I rebooted.
3. I installed the necessary proprietary driver from the terminal:

   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-dkms-515
4. Reboot.
5. only then updated aptitude by

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get upgrade
6. Reboot and check whether the system works now finely.